# Sort on array elements inside the documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "customer1",
    "verarray" : [ 
        "10.5.0-50_0", 
        "11.5.0-30_0"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "customer2",
    "verarray" : [ 
        "11.0.0-30_0", 
        "11.5.0-80_0", 
        "12.5.0-111_0", 
        "13.3.0.21_0.31125", 
        "13.5.0-20_0"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "customer3",
    "verarray" : [ 
        "11.5.0-95_0", 
        "12.6.0.131_0.33392", 
        "10.0.0-5_0", 
        "11.5.0.20_0.22028", 
        "12.6.0.131_0.33392"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the 3rd customer array is not in order. I want to sort each `verarray`. How do I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` to unwind array, sort it & then re-create the same array by grouping on condition `_id`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$verarray" },
  { $sort: { verarray: 1 } }, // Using 1 for asc & use -1 for desc order
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", verarray: { $push: "$verarray" } } }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lQrXj2qOdBI)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it must have been something simple that just escaped me:)